# Create a table with data from a linked server and creating a custom formula column on some of the data collected

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to setup a custom table from a clients accounting data using Microsoft SQL server 2014. I have my own SQL server running that I setup a linked server to. What i am trying to do now, is create a script that i can run manually to update my custom table with data from the linked server (which i got working with just the raw data), but i need to also run some formulas on the retrieved data that will display in the same table in a new column.

Here is the code i currently got completed sofar:

```
USE DVreports
DROP TABLE DVreports.dbo.DV_UnitPOInvoice

CREATE TABLE dbo.DV_UnitPOInvoice (
    UnitID varchar(35) null,
    UnitPOInvoiceID int not null,
    InvoiceID varchar(35) not null,
    InvoiceNum varchar(20) null,
    InvoiceDate datetime not null,
    Status varchar(20) null,
    Total money null,
    AmountPaid money null,
    Paid bit not null,
    LastModifiedOn datetime not null
    );
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.DV_UnitPOInvoice (UnitID, UnitPOInvoiceID, InvoiceID, InvoiceDate, Status, Total, AmountPaid, Paid, LastModifiedOn)
SELECT UnitPOInvoiceItem.UnitID,
       UnitPOInvoice.UnitPOInvoiceID, 
       UnitPOInvoice.InvoiceID, 
       UnitPOInvoice.InvoiceDate, 
       UnitPOInvoice.Status, 
       UnitPOInvoice.Total, 
       UnitPOInvoice.AmountPaid, 
       UnitPOInvoice.Paid, 
       UnitPOInvoice.LastModifiedOn
FROM [HDE-SERVER].[FCIDealerVu].[dbo].[UnitPOInvoice], [HDE-SERVER].[FCIDealerVu].[dbo].[UnitPOInvoiceItem]
WHERE UnitPOInvoice.UnitPOInvoiceID = UnitPOInvoiceItem.UnitPOInvoiceID AND 
      UnitPOInvoiceItem.UnitID>'59000'


INSERT INTO dbo.DV_UnitPOInvoice (InvoiceNum)
SELECT LEFT([DV_UnitPOInvoice].[InvoiceID], isnull((CHARINDEX('-',[DV_UnitPOInvoice].[InvoiceID]-1)) - 1, 10)) FROM [DV_UnitPOInvoice]
```

When I run this i get the error:

```
(2504 row(s) affected)
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '195849-955648' to data type int.
```

The custom column needs to be nullable and varchar(20) data type, as it can contain either numbers or characters. And be blank depending on what is seen from the source data.

I hope this explains things ok, as i am not that fluent in programming yet. I am still working on teaching myself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not related to this error, but you incorrectly use the linked servers. It's highly not recommended to join the tables that are sourced from remote servers using SERVER_NAME.DB_NAME.SCHEMA.TABLE notation. You should use OPENQUERY to execute the query on remote server rather than pull two tables and then join it locally.
2. From the error description you may notice the first insert was successful ((2504 row(s) affected)), so the problem is in 2nd one. I think the problem is here:

   [DV_UnitPOInvoice].[InvoiceID]-1

as [DV_UnitPOInvoice].[InvoiceID] is varchar.

Comment: Ty for the insight on using linked servers. I am still learning, and there is so much to learn still. I will look up on how to correctly use the OPENQUERY function. And with the error, I tried changing it the way you mentioned and still did not work completely. It was a different error though. I will try to re-create the error so I get the exact message for you (I have tried a few different things and I didn't record the messages). But the main part I remember from the new error was that I couldn't have a negative result from the formula.

Comment: That error was also expected. CHARINDEX() returns 0 (not NULL) when it cannot find the string. So this is the reason why you have negative parameter for LEFT function. You can use CASE WHEN... THEN... ELSE... END to handle it, or NULLIF(CHARINDEX(...), 0) function - NULLIF returns NULL here when CHARINDEX returns zero.